# вывести на печать имена экземпляров класса (имена элементов массива обьектов)

Tags: java, вывод

есть массив `Food a[]={duck,hamster2,duck3,hamster17,hamster18,hamster19};`
без переопределения метод Arrays.toString(a) выводит просто hash-code. После переопределения

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() + "[name="  + "]";
}
```

вывод на печать обоими способами

```
System.out.println("print arrayInt after filling " + Arrays.toString(a) );

        System.out.println("print arrayInt after filling " + Arrays.deepToString(a));
```

дает такой результат:

```
print arrayInt after filling [Food[name=], Food[name=], Food[name=], Food[name=], Food[name=], Food[name=]]
```

вопрос- как получить такой список: Food[duck][Food[name=humster], Food[name=duck2], Food[name=duck3], Food[name=hamster3]

eще у обьектов есть параметры, тоже нужно иметь возможность их выводить.

```
[Food[name=humster, weight=2000, color=white]
```

Comment: ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо переопределить `toString()` у класса `Food`. В нём рефлексией пройтись по всем полям. Примерно так:

```java
class Food {
    
    private String name;
    private int weight;
    private String color;

    public Food(String name, int weight, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final String DELIMITER = ", ";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("Food[");
        Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field: fields){
            try {
                stringBuilder.append(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(this)).append(DELIMITER);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.delete(stringBuilder.length() - DELIMITER.length(), stringBuilder.length()).append("]");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Тогда такое:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Food[] foods = {new Food("hamster", 100, "white"), new Food("horse", 1000, "black")};
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(foods));
}
```

выведет:

`[Food[name = hamster, weight = 100, color = white], Food[name = horse, weight = 1000, color = black]]`

Answer (score 0):

Ну переопределите правильно метод `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() + "[name = "  +  name + ", weight = " + weight + ", color = " + color + "]";
}
```

Если вам не нужно чтоб каждый элемент списка оборачивался в квадратные скобки `[]` то распечатывайте не методом `Arrays.toString()`, а с помощью цикла:

```
for(Food food : foods){
    System.out.print(food.toString + ", ");
}
```

Comment: да, как взять имя переменной?

Comment: Food duck = new Food; как программно достать "duck"

Comment: Покажите класс  Food

Comment: это не мой класс. Я так вопрос понял

Comment: Вопрос не мой я имею ввиду

Comment: Если у него нет переменной внутри класса, то как ее можно куда-то вывести?

Comment: На самом деле не понятно откуда у вас такая задача и зачем вам имена переменных которые оптимизатором удаляются в нормальных условиях.

Comment: и правильно переменной может и не быть вовсе для объекта, не забывайте и про это

Comment: return getClass().getSimpleName() + "[name = "  +  name + ", weight = " + weight + ", color = " + white + "]";

так не получается, т.е. параметры то можно выводить, а вот name - это же не параметр. Duck - это имя экземпляра класса.

`Food duck = new Food(3000);
        Food hamster2 = new Food(2000);`

Comment: `Food duck = new Food(3000);
        Food hamster2 = new Food(2000);`
сам класс такой-
` public class Food implements CompareWeight
{
    private int weight;
    Food(int weight)
    {
        this.weight=weight;
    }`